# python generator endless stream without using yield

Tags: python, generator

i'm trying to generate an endless stream of results given a function f and an initial value x
so first call should give the initial value, second call should give f(x), third call is f(x2) while x2 is the previous result of f(x) and so on..

what i have come up with:

```
def generate(f, x): 
   return itertools.repeat(lambda x: f(x))
```

which does not  seem to work. any ideas? (i cant use yield in my code). also i cant use more than 1 line of code for this problem. any help would be appreciated.

also note that in a previous ex. i was asked to use the yield. with no problems:

```
while True:
    yield x
    x = f(x)
```

this works fine. but now.. no clue how to do it without

Comment: What's with those constraints? Seems fairly artificial?

Comment: Wow ... whoever gave you this assignment should re-think it... As far as I see it, this is an exercise in teaching people to do a task *the wrong way*

Comment: @NPE And that too in one line. :(

Comment: yep, i had a previous assignment doing it with yield. ill edit my post

Comment: hmm well it works fine for the yield.

Comment: @mgilson I think that while loop is an alternate body to the same `generate` function he has defined above, just without the function declaration enclosing it.  Then it would work fine.

Comment: @SilasRay -- I missed that OP said first call should give the initial value.  I thought the first call should give `f(x)`.

Comment: Have a look here may be u find something useful.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737196/an-expression-for-an-infinite-generator..

Comment: Also if you are using `itertools.repeat()` then it uses `yield` internally... so one way or the other you will have to use `yield`...
look here 
http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3.3, you can use `itertools.accumulate`:

```
import itertools

def generate(f, x):
  return itertools.accumulate(itertools.repeat(x), lambda v,_:f(v))

for i, val in enumerate(generate(lambda x: 2*x, 3)):
  print(val)
  if i == 10:
    break
```

Comment: I think the function argument only arrived in 3.3.

Comment: @DSM: That's right, thanks! (I quite liked the narrative in your answer BTW.)

Comment: this works fine! also thank everyone else who helped!

Answer (score 4):

I think this works:

```
import itertools as it
def g(f, x):
    return it.chain([x],(setattr(g, 'x', f(getattr(g, 'x', x))) or getattr(g, 'x') for _ in it.count()))

def f(x):
    return x + 1

gen = g(f, 1)
print next(gen)
print next(gen)
print next(gen)
print next(gen)
```

Of course, it relys on some sketchy behavior where I actually add an attribute to the function itself to keep the state.  Basically, this function will only work the first time you call it.  After that, all bets are off.

If we want to relax that restriction, we can use a temporary namespace.  The problem is that to get a temporary namespace we need a unique class instance (or class, but an instance is cleaner and only requires 1 extra set of parenthesis).  To make that happen in one line, we need to create a new function inline and use that as a default argument:

```
import itertools as it
def g(f, x):
    return (lambda f, x, ns=type('foo', (object,), {})(): \
        it.chain([x], 
                 (setattr(ns, 'x', f(getattr(ns, 'x', x))) or getattr(ns, 'x') 
                          for _ in it.count()))
            )(f, x)

def f(x):
    return x + 1

gen = g(f, 1)
print next(gen) == 1
print next(gen) == 2
print next(gen) == 3
print next(gen) == 4

print "first worked?"
gen2 = g(f, 2)
print next(gen2) == 2
print next(gen2) == 3
print next(gen2) == 4
```

I've broken it into a few lines, for readability, but it's a 1-liner at heart.

## A version without any imports

(and the most robust one yet I believe).

```
def g(f, x):
    return iter(lambda f=f, x=x, ns=type('foo', (object,), {'x':x}): ((getattr(ns, 'x'),setattr(ns, 'x', f(getattr(ns, 'x'))))[0]), object())
```

One trick here is the same as before.  We create a lambda function with a mutable default argument to keep the state.  Inside the function, we build a tuple.  The first item is what we actually want, the second item is the return value of the `setattr` function which is used to update the state.  In order to get rid of the `itertools.chain`, we set the initial value on the namespace to the value of `x` so the class is already initialzed to have the starting state.  The second trick is that we use the two argument form of `iter` to get rid of `it.count()` which was only used to create an infinite iterable before.  `iter` keeps calling the function you give it as the first argument until the return value is equal to the second argument.  However, since my second argument is an instance of `object`, nothing returned from our function will ever be equal to it so we've effectively created an infinite iterable without `itertools` or `yield`!  Come to think of it, I believe this last version is the most robust too.  Previous versions had a bug where they relied on the truthfulness of the return value of `f`.  I think they might have failed if `f` returned `0`.  This last version fixes that bug.

Comment: I was thinking of the mutable default argument state hack.

Comment: @DSM -- Yeah, that would work too.  I actually got rid of that statefulness problem by returning the return value of a lambda function with mutable state :)

Comment: FWIW, I think this takes it for the most obfuscated python code I've ever written ...  Thanks professor.

Comment: Your new code is.. a bunch of characters one could type. |^)  I may "borrow" this approach for the next round of one-liner golf!

Comment: I reckon that `chain` and `count` can be gotten rid of :)

Comment: @JonClements -- If you can figure out how, I'm open to suggestions.  While trying, my brain started to hurt, so I stopped trying.

Comment: @mgilson I've got an idea... but my brain is protesting... I'll let you know if I manage it :)

Comment: @JonClements I think you could get rid of `count` using the 2 argument form of `iter` ...

Comment: @mgilson yeah... and I was thinking of the two form version of `next` might be able to get rid of the chain... - Something like: `next([lambda x: x], lambda L: f(L))` sort of lines... So the first iteration just has an identity function instead of the actual function

Comment: @JonClements -- I got it!  :).  No imports :).

Comment: @DSM -- Added an importless version for the next time that's a requirement in your code-golfing.

Comment: Now I have to pretend that I've always known about the two-argument version of `iter` and I haven't used it in the past for some artistic reason.  I have mixed feelings about this development.

Comment: To borrow from Bob (I believe) - it should have a disclaimer like: I can see it can you see ̲͚̖͔̙î̩́t̲͎̩̱͔́̋̀ it is beautiful t​he final snuffing of the lie​s of Man ALL IS LOŚ͖̩͇̗̪̏̈́T ALL I​S LOST the pon̷y he comes he c̶̮omes he comes the ich​or permeates all MY FACE MY FACE ᵒh god no NO NOO̼O​O NΘ stop the an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e n​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

Comment: @DSM -- Don't feel bad.  I don't think I've ever used the 2 argument form of `iter` in a single piece of code that I've actually used for something other than a SO answer where there was some silly constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is some sort of homework or assignment?  As such, I'd say you should take a look at [generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).  Though I agree with the other commenters that this seems an exercise of dubious value...

Comment: yea i was thinking itertools also, but the only one that seems to do the trick is imap?

Comment: I misread the question slightly and was thinking about `count`.  That won't work for what you want, though you may be able to shoehorn something in to something from `itertools`...