# python generator expression from generator , is it possible?

Tags: python

i am trying to convert my function i want it do the same as:

```
    def get_num(function, starting_index):
        yield starting_index
        while True:
            yield function(starting_index)
            starting_index = function(starting_index)
```

so im i want the new function to return a genexp that does exactly the same, of course without using 'yield', and all in one line, is possible?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this? IMHO, this looks much better than the generator expression equivalent.

Comment: Half homework, half teaching myself, i don't necessarily need a code, an idea, or the beginning of something is good too!

Comment: @TimPeters my "favourite" being [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248760/python-generator-endless-stream-without-using-yield/20249240#20249240)

Comment: What kind of awful homework is this?! It doesn't teach you how to program, it teaches you how to use Stack Overflow to find ways to horribly abuse whichever language it's set for.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first, you might want to avoid redundant calls to the function:

```
def get_num(fn, start):
    while True:
        yield start
        start = fn(start)
```

Comment: thanks, but not what i asked

Answer (score 0):

A recursive version of your original function:

```
def get_num(f, x):
    yield x
    yield from get_num(f, f(x))
```

On the same theme:

```
>>> p = lambda x, f, c: chain((x,), (i for i in p(f(x), f, c))) if c(x) else (x, None)
>>> p(1, lambda x: x*2, lambda x: x < 100)
<itertools.chain object at 0x01633DD0>
>>> list(_)
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, None]
```

This does what the original function does, but stops if `x` satisfies some condition.

Then because it has to be a generator expression?! we do this:

```
>>> g = (i for i in _)
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
2
>>> next(g)
4
>>> next(g)
8
>>> next(g)
16
```

The conditional function `c` is necessary to stop infinite recursion. If Python was a bit more of a functional language (i.e. lazy evaluation being more common, and tail recursion being optimized) then this wouldn't be necessary.