# Iterated function in Python

Tags: python

Given a function `f( )`, a number `x` and an integer `N`, I want to compute the List:

```
y = [x, f(x), f(f(x)), ..., f(f... M times...f(f(x)) ]
```

An obvious way to do this in Python is the following Python code:

```
y = [x]
for i in range(N-1):
    y.append(f(y[-1]))
```

But I want to know if there is a better or faster, way to do this.

Comment: should the line in the for loop be, "y.append(f(y[-1]))"

Comment: @Ryaan G: yes, it should be, thank you.

Comment: What is f? Maybe it can be solved without needing to apply the function repeatedly. Trivial example: def f(n): return n + 1

Comment: Note that in Python >= 3.3, there's an [accumulate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248760/python-generator-endless-stream-without-using-yield)-based approach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several ways to optimize this code:

1. It is faster to using `itertools.repeat(None, times)` to control the number of loops (this avoids creating new, unused integer objects on every iteration).
2. You can gain speed by putting this in a function or generator (local variables are faster than global variables.
3. You can gain speed by saving the intermediate results in a variable, avoiding the `[-1]` indexed lookup (LOAD_FAST / STORE_FAST is quicker than LOAD_CONST -1 and BINARY_SUBSCR).
4. You can improve speed by using a pre-bound method instead of `y.append`.

For example:

```
from itertools import repeat

def nest(func, x, times):
     result = [x]
     result_append = result.append
     for _ in repeat(None, times):
         x = func(x)
         result_append(x)
     return result
```

Here is a sample call:

```
>>> def double(x):
        return 2 * x

>>> nest(double, 3, 5)
[3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96]
```

Here is the disassembly showing the tight inner-loop, use of local variables, and the bound method:

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(nest)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
              3 BUILD_LIST               1
              6 STORE_FAST               3 (result)

  3           9 LOAD_FAST                3 (result)
             12 LOAD_ATTR                0 (append)
             15 STORE_FAST               4 (result_append)

  4          18 SETUP_LOOP              45 (to 66)
             21 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (repeat)
             24 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             27 LOAD_FAST                2 (times)
             30 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             33 GET_ITER            
        >>   34 FOR_ITER                28 (to 65)
             37 STORE_FAST               5 (_)

  5          40 LOAD_FAST                0 (func)
             43 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             46 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             49 STORE_FAST               1 (x)

  6          52 LOAD_FAST                4 (result_append)
             55 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             58 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             61 POP_TOP             
             62 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           34
        >>   65 POP_BLOCK           

  7     >>   66 LOAD_FAST                3 (result)
             69 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a generator:

```
import itertools

def apply_apply(f, x_0):
    x = x_0
    while True:
        yield x
        x = f(x)

....

y = list(itertools.islice(apply_apply(f, x), N))
```

Another way is to go the fully functional route:

```
from functools import reduce

y = list(reduce(lambda x, f: x + [f(x[-1])], [[x_0]] + [f] * (N - 1)))
```

As a side note, both solutions perform better on my machine than the accepted solution, being 2ms for the generator, 2ms for the functional and 4ms for Raymond's code with `f = lambda x: x * x`, `x_0 = 2` and `N = 20`.

For `lambda x: 2 * x` Raymond's version is slightly faster than the generator approach and a lot faster than the functional variant. It seems to depend on the complexity of `f`, though I don't know how ...

Comment: It is difficult to get meaningful time measurements for list building code.  As the list grows, realloc() is called periodically.  Depending on fragmentation, that call is either instant (overrun space is available) or dog slow (all the data has to be copied).   I would have posted a generator solution (that doesn't have these issues) but the OP specifically asked for a list and asked how to optimize his approach to the problem.