# Python: why is it faster to iterate over a list than iterating over an xrange() generator define on its length?

Tags: python, microbenchmark

Why is iterating over a list faster than iterating over an xrange generator defined on the list length?

Input:

```
timeit.timeit('for _ in dummy: continue', setup='dummy=xrange(10000)', number=100000)
timeit.timeit('for _ in dummy: continue', setup='dummy = [0] * 10000', number=100000)
```

Output:

```
22.131134033203125
17.916101932525635
```

I assume it depends on the ratio between how many of these operations are executed natively in pre-compiled C code.

Comment: what about `for _ in [0]*10000`?

Comment: Wouldn't `dummy=xrange(10000)` vs `dummy=range(10000)` be a fairer comparison? Otherwise you are creating an `xrange` object N times, but only creating your list once.

Comment: @khelwood, it would be.  But in the end, `range(10000)` will be faster than `xrange(10000)`, at least in python2.7.

Comment: @wflynny xrange creates an iterator, range creates a list (in memory), xrange is faster than range in python2.7 (xrange is removed in python 3 and range now creates an iterator)

Comment: @no_name, Using python2.7, with `setup='dummy = xrange(10000)'` I get 0.797435998916626s and with `setup='dummy = range(10000)'`, I get 0.6557648181915283s.

Comment: @khelwood i modified my test and the same results (even 1 second slower)  are there.

Comment: @khelwood `xrange()` is just an iterator, it will hardly takes nano-seconds to create an iterator or generator, OTOH `range()` has to create a whole list in memory first before any iteration actually starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it in Python3 , but the same  results arose. I put the `range` creation in `setup` for a more accurate comparison

```
In [1]: timeit.timeit('for _ in a: continue', setup='a=list(range(10000))', number=10000)
Out[1]: 1.195666481000444

In [2]: timeit.timeit('for _ in a: continue', setup='a=range(10000)', number=10000)
Out[2]: 2.4083170039994
```

I think that the main difference is that `range` is lazily generating `_` value at each iteration, whereas if you use a list it just has to read them from memory. Compare to

```
In [3]: timeit.timeit('for _ in range(10000): continue', number=10000)
Out[3]: 4.166428555001403

In [4]: timeit.timeit('for _ in list(range(10000)): continue', number=10000)
Out[4]: 5.800707030000922
```

where we are taking the time needed to create the objects into account. Which shows the point of lazy evaluation.

Comment: yet, reading from memory is more expensive (even with pre-fetch to cache) than something that could be done completely in registers (xrange).

Comment: @marcorossi Are you sure that xrange is done completely in registers?

Comment: @WayneWerner no, I meant that it could be done by a smart interpreter/compiler. xrange is running in the interpreter with native code anyway.

Comment: Feel free to dig in https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/cb911e1fb3dc/Objects/rangeobject.c (probably around line 755)

Comment: @Evpok, yes I think you're right. It's the object creation.

Answer (score 4):

When we loop over an already created list we're actually iterating over its iterator and calling its `next` method each time, which simply yields the next item from the list as per the internal index([it->it_index](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/325aec842e3e/Objects/listobject.c#l2900)) maintained by it. i.e No new object is created here. On the other hand `range()` in Python 3 or `xrange()` in Python 2 during each iteration Python has to [create a new Long object](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/325aec842e3e/Objects/rangeobject.c#l238), which can be expensive:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('for _ in dummy: continue', setup='dummy = xrange(10**4)', number=100000)
8.74455213546753
>>> timeit.timeit('for _ in dummy: continue', setup='dummy = [0] * 10000', number=100000)
7.1642138957977295
```

If instead of `xrange()` we use `itertools.repeat` with `None` we get some slight improvement because now we are not creating new object during each iteration, simply repeating the same object.

```
>>> timeit.timeit('for _ in repeat(None, 10000): continue', setup='from itertools import repeat', number=100000)
6.986715793609619
```

From Raymond Hettinger's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22103011/846892):

> It is faster to using `itertools.repeat(None, times)` to control the
>   number of loops (this avoids creating new, unused integer objects on
>   every iteration).

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess it's because comparisons are expensive operations. And if `xrange` looks anything like this:

```
def xrange(limit):
    counter = 0
    while counter < limit:
        counter += 1
```

Then you're talking about 10,000 comparisons. As opposed to iterating over the list, which only has to raise `StopIteration` at the end of the list.

But I'm not sure about the internals, so I could be wrong.

Comment: Indeed, @no_name, though that shouldn't make much of a difference (as you're just replacing 0 and 1 with `start` & `stop`). At least I would be massively surprised if it really did make that much difference.

Comment: @wflynny I tried with the setup code in both, with similar results - `xrange` (or `range` in py3) is marginally slower than iterating over the collection.

Comment: Also the code that raises the StopIteration will have to check the length of the array though.

Comment: Are you sure that it checks the length? I'm just reasoning, I don't know the source for sure, but if Python lists are implemented in C and are effectively a linked list, iteration over the list would be doing a comparison in C to check `null` on `next`. That's a much *much* faster comparison than anything that will happen in Python.

Comment: Oh yes, I meant that the interpreter is doing it. But then we go to the point where most of the iteration is done by the interpreter in C, more than just the comparison.

Comment: xrange is also native code built-in, not python code. I just checked.

Comment: @WayneWerner Python [[lists are not linked-lists](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented), they are just arrays. That's why indexing is so fast. And coming to comparisons, they are happening in list's methods as well: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/325aec842e3e/Objects/listobject.c#l2900

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `xrange`, I assume Python 2.x.  The exact setup of the experiment is important.

## Using dummy variable (xrange slower)

```
timeit.timeit('for _ in dummy: continue', setup='dummy = range(10000)', number=100000)
```

> `13.719306168122216`

```
timeit.timeit('for _ in dummy: continue', setup='dummy = xrange(10000)', number=100000)
```

> `15.667266362411738`

## Without dummy variable (xrange faster)

However, if we take the dummy variable out of the picture:

```
timeit.timeit('for _ in range(10000): continue', number=100000)
```

> `20.79111238831547`

```
timeit.timeit('for _ in xrange(10000): continue', number=100000)
```

> `15.494247599682467`

## Why?

**Dummy variable difference**

This indicates that the `xrange` variable is cheap to set up, but slightly more expensive to iterate through.  In the first instance, you set up an object only once, but iterate through 100000 times.  In the second, you set up 100000 times, iterating each once.  Interesting - as the documentation for `xrange` would have you believe the opposite (my emphasis):

> Like range(), but instead of returning a list, returns an object that
>   generates the numbers in the range on demand.  **For looping, this is
>   slightly faster than range() and more memory efficient.**

**Code difference**

Looking at [the C code where `xrange` is implemented](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/rangeobject.c), we see:

```
...

/*********************** Xrange Iterator **************************/

typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    long        index;
    long        start;
    long        step;
    long        len;
} rangeiterobject;

static PyObject *
rangeiter_next(rangeiterobject *r)
{
    if (r->index < r->len)
        return PyInt_FromLong(r->start + (r->index++) * r->step);
    return NULL;
}

...
```

So, each call to get the next number from `xrange` results in a comparison as [suggested by @WayneWerner as a reason for slower iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28723822/838992)

***EDIT***

Note - I use `range(10000)` to contrast with `xrange(10000)`, however, the results hold using the OP's `[0]*10000` also