# Infinite Series in Python

Tags: python, kotlin

Is there any function in Python that provides an infinite series similar to generateSequence in Kotlin?

In Kotlin I can do something like:

```
generateSequence(1) { it + 1 }.take(5).forEach { println(it) }
```

Obviously this stops with an integer overflow error but I would like to do something similar in Python.

Comment: This SO thread will be of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737196/is-there-an-expression-for-an-infinite-generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write a simple `generator`

```
def count(x):
    while True:
        yield x
        x += 1

for i in count(5):
    print(i)
```

of coarse this particular generator is builtin with `itertools.count`

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.count(5):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to get a `count` object that generates an infinite sequence of values.

You can take the first *n* items by explicitly retrieving the next item from the `count` object for the required number of times. Alternatively, and preferably, use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to take the first *n* items.

Mirroring your example, to take the first 5 values of the sequence using explicit iteration:

```
from itertools import count

c = count(1)    # start from 1 instead of 0
for i in range(5):
    print(next(c))
```

Or using [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
for n in islice(count(1), 5):
    print(n)
```